# How to convert Python JSON to API call string from dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

My script reads parameters from an Excel file using *pandas*.

1. The code first reads from an excel file and creates a `DataFrame`, `df`.
2. The `df` is filtered on `df['Team'] == 'IT'`.
3. Filtered `df` is converted to JSON to get all parameters and values.

**This is the code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import json

loc = "excel.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(loc)

# "Team" is filtered by 'IT'
rslt_df = df[df["Team"] == 'IT'] 

# Encoding a DataFrame using "columns" formatted JSON
result = rslt_df.to_json(orient="columns")

# Parse json results
parsed = json.loads(result)
```

**The `df` output filtered on `"Team"` using `"IT"`**

```
   StartDate    EndDate startTime   endTime      Team   RotationID     Users
0 2021-04-01 2021-04-02  17:00:00  01:00:00      IT     081435f       john@dotdansh.io
2 2021-04-02 2021-04-03  17:00:00  01:00:00      IT     081435f       paul@dotdansh.io
4 2021-04-03 2021-04-04  17:00:00  01:00:00      IT     081435f       danny@dotdansh.io
6 2021-04-04 2021-04-05  17:00:00  01:00:00      IT     081435f       ben@dotdansh.io
```

**JSON output from filtered `df` using the `'columns'` data structure:**

```
{
    "StartDate": {"0": "2021-04-01", "2": "2021-04-02", "4": "2021-04-03", "6": "2021-04-04"},
    "EndDate": {"0": "2021-04-02", "2": "2021-04-03", "4": "2021-04-04", "6": "2021-04-05"},
    "startTime": {"0": "17:00:00", "2": "17:00:00", "4": "17:00:00", "6": "17:00:00"},
    "endTime": {"0": "01:00:00", "2": "01:00:00", "4": "01:00:00", "6": "01:00:00"},
    "Team": {"0": "IT", "2": "IT", "4": "IT", "6": "IT"},
    "RotationID": {"0": "081435f", "2": "081435f", "4": "081435f", "6": "081435f"},
    "User": {"0": "john@dotdansh.io", "2": "paul@dotdansh.io", "4": "danny@dotdansh.io", "6": "ben@dotdansh.io"}
}
```

I need to create an API `PATCH` request with the parameters received from the JSON below.
Note that the values can be different and the count of values, as well.

**This is the data string of the API patch call with the required parameters:**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Key <myKey>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
data = ' { "name": "<Team>", "startDate": "<first_startDate>T<first_startTime>Z", "endDate": "<last_endDate>T<last_endTime>Z",\
 "type": "daily", "length": 1,\
 "participants": [\.    ##list of users
 { "type": "user",\
      "username": "john@dotdansh.io" },\
 { "type": "user",\
      "username": "paul@dotdansh.io"}\
 ] } }'
response = requests.patch('https://example.com', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: I updated your question. Remember that sorting is just ordering something. The number of elements don't change. What you were doing is called filtering, the point of filtering is to remove elements, not reordering them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using groupby to lump together the users, and then orientation `'records'` instead of `'columns'`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Team', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'RotationID']).agg(tuple).reset_index()

for record in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    payload = {
        "name": record['Team'],
        "startDate": record['StartDate'],
        "endDate": record['EndDate'],
        "rotationid": record['RotationID'],
        "participants": [{ "type": "user", "username": user } for user in record['User']]
    }
    requests.patch('https://example.com/endpoint', data=payload)
```

`groupby()` creates and object which you can run an aggregation on, like `sum()` or `mean()`. But in this case we want all results, so we "aggregate" using the `tuple` constructor. That means Users end up in a `tuple` per group. Because groupby adds what you group by to the index, I remove the index at the end so that the `to_dict()` function returns them too. Your example data didn't have multiple users in one group, so I added on in my run and got the following payloads:

```
{'name': 'IT', 'startDate': '2021-04-01', 'endDate': '2021-04-02', 'rotationid': '081435f', 'participants': [{'type': 'user', 'username': 'john@dotdansh.io'}]}
{'name': 'IT', 'startDate': '2021-04-02', 'endDate': '2021-04-03', 'rotationid': '081435f', 'participants': [{'type': 'user', 'username': 'paul@dotdansh.io'}]}
{'name': 'IT', 'startDate': '2021-04-03', 'endDate': '2021-04-04', 'rotationid': '081435f', 'participants': [{'type': 'user', 'username': 'danny@dotdansh.io'}]}
{'name': 'IT', 'startDate': '2021-04-04', 'endDate': '2021-04-05', 'rotationid': '081435f', 'participants': [{'type': 'user', 'username': 'ben@dotdansh.io'}, {'type': 'user', 'username': 'other@dotdansh.io'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew, 
If I am not mistaken your code will create `PATCH` requests per existing record, I want to make one `PATCH` request with the first `startDate` `startTime` and the last `endDate` `endTime` , list of `users` like you mentioned.
the `Team` needs to be filtered because there are several `Team` records in the Excel file and I need to make one API request for each `Team`.

Comment: I have updated my API `PATCH` request in my question.

Comment: Hey Andre, Did you have a chance to look at my comment?